# Generic types: how to get the most common character from an Generic type array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Im struggling with ArrayLists and my method `public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T items[])` has to return the most common character (or String, or Integer, or Double) and how many times it is met inside the array. Suppose `new String[]{"a","b","a"}`, so the method should return `"a", 2`. Or, another example, `new Integer[]{30,10,10,20}` should return `10, 2` (number 10 is met twice inside the array). Please SOMEBODY GUIDE ME TO THE RIGHT TRACK? Take into accoung that I'm not allowed to use Maps, Collections... only ArrayLists!

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mode {

    public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T items[])
    {
        ArrayList<T> trackItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for(T values: items)
        {
            trackItems.add(values);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < trackItems.size(); i++)
        {
            int count = (Integer)trackItems.get(i);
        }

    }
}
    public class Pair<X,Y>{
      private X first;
      private Y second;

      public Pair(X x, Y y){
        this.first = x;
        this.second = y;
      }

      public X getFirst(){
        return this.first;
      }
      public Y getSecond(){
        return this.second;
      }

      public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(!(o instanceof Pair)){
          return false;
        }
        Pair p = (Pair) o;
        return
          this.first.equals(p.first) &&
          this.second.equals(p.second);
      }

      public String toString(){
        return String.format("(%s,%s)",first,second);
      }

    }
```

Comment: Well, what problem do you face?

Comment: How should I find out the most common letter or int using Generics? @Tarik

Comment: If you're using Java 8, ArrayList has a sort method, which would make it easy for you to group and count items.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an array list of that `Pair` class of yours to simulate a map.

make type `X` the same type as the type you're matching against, and type `Y` an int.  `first` represents the character, and `Y` represents the number of times it's occurred.

- make an `ArrayList` of `Pair`
- iterate over your source list, and at every iteration, search your new ArrayList for an element who's `first` is equal to your current element.
- if you find one, add 1 to the `second` element.
- if you don't find one, add one, initializing the `second` element to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SamIam... in order to make ArrayList of Pair, is it ArrayList <Pair<T, Integer>> = new ArrayList<>() ???

Comment: @Inferno you should be able to check and see if that works yourself

Comment: @Inferno What's happening wen you try that

Answer (score 0):

Its assumed that you'd use this answer to understand how to approach such problems, and not blatantly copy the answer to finish up your assignment if it is the case.

Since the `Pair` class has its second parameter as an `Integer` only, I'd define it as follows for the sake of simplicity:

```
public class Pair<T>
{
  private T value;
  private int count;

  public Pair (T value, int count)
  {
    this.value = value;
    this.count = count;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString ()
  {
    return String.format ("Pair: [%s, %s]", value, count);
  }
}
```

Now, the `Mode` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Mode
{
  public static <T extends Comparable> Pair<T> mode (ArrayList<T> items) throws Exception
  {
    if (items == null)
    {
      throw new NullPointerException ("Items Can't be Null");
    }
    else if (items.size () == 0)
    {
      throw new Exception ("Items needs to be more than 0");
    }

    items.sort (Comparator.<T>naturalOrder ());

    int maxCount = 1;
    int itemCount = 0;

    T maxItem = items.get (0);
    T currentItem = items.get (0);

    for (T item : items)
    {
      if (item.equals (currentItem))
      {
        itemCount++;
      }
      else if (itemCount > maxCount)
      {
        maxCount = itemCount;
        itemCount = 0;

        maxItem = currentItem;
        currentItem = item;
      }
    }

    return new Pair<T> (maxItem, maxCount);
  }
}
```

In this, I make sure that `T` is `Comparable` by using the `T extends Comparable` line. This is done so that the `ArrayList<T>` can be sorted using a sort method.

Next, in the `mode` function, I first check if the `ArrayList<T> items` is `null` or has `0` items in it. If it is the case, I throw proper exception.

Next I sort the `items`. So if the `ArrayList` was of `Integer`s and the items were `10, 20, 10`, then after sort it'd be `10, 10, 20`.

Then I assume that the element with the maximum count is the first element.

After this I loop through the items to see if the next item is equal to the previous item. If it is, I increment the `itemCount`. If it isn't, I check if the `maxCount` is less than the `itemCount`. If such is the case, then I update my `maxItem`, `currentItem` and `maxCount`, and reset the `itemCount` and repeat the process again.

Once the loop is over, I'll have in `maxItem` the value which has the highest frequency, and `maxCount` will hold that frequency.

Following is a sample test to demonstrate it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList (10, 20, 10));
    System.out.println (Mode.mode (integers));

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList ("a", "b", "a", "a"));
    System.out.println (Mode.mode (strings));
  }
}
```

The output is:
`Pair: [10, 2]`
`Pair: [a, 3]`

Which is as expected, unless I read your question wrong.

Comment: @Tarik: Well at least I got one funny comment for this answer. Haha. I wasn't really expecting any reputation point when I answered it. In fact I'm more glad that I didn't get any down votes. LOL. New comers tend to ask such questions and the old hats here create a barrier of entry by giving down votes to such questions. True that some are here just for their assignment and don't really bother about the concepts, but the fact is none of them know how to approach the problem or else they wouldn't have asked it in the first place. And so with my answer I tried to explain the approach.

Comment: What you said is true. SO is often unforgiving. It's not obvious to balance out between helping and outright doing a homework.  Maybe shall we deal with such situations by guiding the person progressively or by pointing to relevant resources.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (1, albeit longish, line) solution that doesn't use any objects, just methods:

```
public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T[] items) {
    return Arrays.stream(items)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o, Collectors.counting()))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue())
      .findFirst().get()
      .map(e -> new Pair(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```